# Error when use custom tool on edmx.tt

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, devforce

I am trying to compile code for my company legency program, it uses DevForce 2010 and i use a clean computer with win7 and VS2015 to complile the project

During compiling, i hit an error when trying to use custom tool to generate the entity file on edmx.tt and i receive the following error

I have DevForce 2010 6.1.16.0

I understand its some file not found, but it looks like all the dependent are installed. need help

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Running transformation: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could
>   not load file or assembly 'IdeaBlade.EntityModel.Edm.Metadata,
>   Version=6.1.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=287b5094865421c0' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   File name: 'IdeaBlade.EntityModel.Edm.Metadata, Version=6.1.16.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=287b5094865421c0'    at
>   IdeaBlade.VisualStudio.OM.CodeGenerator.BaseDomainModelTemplate..ctor(Object
>   textTransformation)    at
>   IdeaBlade.VisualStudio.OM.CodeGenerator.DomainModelTemplate..ctor(Object
>   textTransformation)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingDEA9D3B21514CE4FC95E8376F9A7F75AB666800A9E7D8F8E8E09AD83552E00B7B56F9D59718DB1618A52DFA05F11232EC3FD39E1A41B91AE0EE9E264ED6270A2.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText()
>   in C:\Users\cat\Desktop\cat\cat\ITSDBModel.edmx.tt:line 8

[[image: Properties of the edmx]]

Comment: when you are referencing the assemblies did you also manually add those to the references as well as the using section in the class header..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DevForce version 6.1.16 doesn't actually support VS2015.  The "DevForce EDM Designer Extension", which extends the EDM Designer with additional DevForce properties and provides code generation of the DevForce model, won't be installed with VS2015.  Other components of DF which don't specifically involve VS integration will be installed though, which makes things confusing.  You're getting the error because this extension isn't installed and the required assemblies aren't available.

IdeaBlade never released a version of DF2010 which supports VS2015.

You have a couple different options -

1. If you have access to VS2013 (or VS2012 or VS2010) you can work with the legacy project in one of those IDEs.
2. If you're a licensed customer, contact [IdeaBlade](https://www.ideablade.com/contact-us) and they can work something out - most likely provide you with a customized EDMX extension to get you past the problem.
3. DF2010 was mostly superseded by DF2012, which does include support for VS2015 (and will support VS2017 later this year).  An upgrade isn't necessarily painless if your project is large or complex, but that could be something to think about.  DF2010 licenses also work in DF2012.

For more information on the 6.1.16 release, see the [release notes](http://drc.ideablade.com/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/6116-release-notes).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have MSDN so I just download VS2013 and all works out.